# CentOS MySQL loading website PHP taking too long after reboot?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I'm doing a remote connection from a WebHost to a **CentOS** server. I have used to restart it after a few days, but yesterday when I tried I rebooted it and the website that tries to connect to the remote MySQL on the CentOS server was going so slow. Like it literally took a few minutes for the page to load.

I don't really get why? however, I had to re-do the access part to make the WebHost able to connect again. Why'd that happen? It was just a normal reboot? Now I have fixed that, but it is very slow.

It could be something with the cache, but it has never happened before? If so, how to fix that. But again, it's weird since the local website doesn't have any trouble and loads extremely fast. Before it took only a few ms before the site was loaded.

Comment: Are you using the IP address of the remote host to connect? or a domain name? I've had issues in the past where using the domain name was slower due to some DNS issues. Changing to using the IP address fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @SheppardDigital I'm using IP :) Opened the port and made a MySQL user with access to the database.